# Bing Autosuggest Dropdown Responsive CSS

Tags: html, css, bing-maps

I am testing out the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-concepts/autosuggest-module-examples/default-autosuggest-user-interface-example). The only difference is my `searchBox` is responsive and has 100% width.

```
<div id='searchBoxContainer'>
   <input type='text' id='searchBox' style="width:100%"/>
</div>
```

On mobile the `searchBoxContainer` does not honor the width of the `searchBox`. The red overhang below expands my mobile app and doesn't feel good.

[image]

I have determined I can fix this by setting the `as_container max-width` equal to the width of the `searchBox` as it changes.

```
#as_container { 
max-width: width of search box;
}
```

Is there a way to set the `#as_container max-width` dynamically as the `searchBox` width changes? I've fixed this with `$(window).resize` and a little javascript but I feel like there is CSS to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with. It's really simple I would just prefer a CSS solution. In my case the `searchBox` is responsive to it's container, `style="width:100%"`. On resize I match bings drop down container's `max-width` to the `searchBox`. The container's width can be set with `#as_container`.

```
        // Our responsive fix for the autosuggest is to limit it's max width to the dropdown container. (Assuming our searchBox is responsive, we'll match widths)
        function FixAutoSuggest() {
            try {
                var css = document.getElementById("autoSuggestFix");
                // Create a CSS element for our fix if it hasn't been created already.
                if (!css) {
                    css = document.createElement("style");
                    css.setAttribute("id", "autoSuggestFix");
                    css.type = "text/css";
                    document.body.appendChild(css);
                }
                // Set the appropriate width for our auto suggest container.
                var searchBox = document.getElementById('searchBox')
                if (searchBox != null) {
                    var bb = searchBox.getBoundingClientRect(), columnWidth = bb.right - bb.left;
                    // We set column width minimum to 150.
                    columnWidth = ((columnWidth > 150) ? columnWidth : 150);
                    css.innerHTML = "#as_container { max-width: " + columnWidth + "px }";
                }
            }
            catch (err) {
                alert('FixAutoSuggest' + err);
            }

        }

        $(window).resize(function () {
            FixAutoSuggest();
        });
```

In my case the search box is not shown initially and I call `FixAutoSuggest()` when showing it. If you show it on load you could always fix then as well.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        FixAutoSuggest();
    });
```

You'll notice in `FixAutoSuggest()` I put a minimum width of `150px` on the bing drop down. That's just personal preference and you can remove that line if you want it to shrink to nothing. Hope this helps someone!